# cancelled flight from Israel

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, israel, aeroflot

I wonder whether anyone can help and / or point me to the right direction. 
We boarded a flight from Israel to Moscow (Aeroflot Russian Airlines) and after about 1.5 hours were told the flight was cancelled. We have an official paper to this extent, and an official email from the airline that the cancellation was due to mechanical error. 
The airline did provide overnight accommodation and re-issued tickets to the next available flight which was 24 hours later.

I wonder whether the compensation clause applies to my case (of course the airline denies this!) as the cancellation was post the boarding.

Also, just in case this matters, we are not citizens of either country.

Comment: If it’s Aeroflot, as the tag suggests, then EU compensation rules will not apply regardless.

Comment: Sorry, is this forum only about EU laws? If so, I'm sorry. The law that applies / may apply is the Israeli Aviation Services Law.

Comment: @JannaRaikhman the EU compensation rules are the most common ones that get asked about, and almost certainly form the basis of Willekes query - an EU airline flying into the EU would be subject to EU261 and thus you would be eligible for compensation.  I was just pointing out that the question was already tagged with an airline, and the combination of origin and airline would preclude EU rules applying.  That doesn’t rule out Israeli or Russian rules applying (or wherever the destination country is).

Comment: Thank you. Even if the flight was cancelled after the boarding?

Comment: @DavidsupportsMonica just a note, but for ‘c’ to apply, ‘a’ must also be true - flights into the EU by a non-EU airline are not covered.

Comment: @Moo Thanks for the correction. I'll delete and re-post my comment.

Comment: @JannaRaikhman EU rules apply if a) it's an EU carrier (Aeroflot isn't), b) the flight departs from an EU country (this one didn't), or c) the flight is both destined for an EU destination (this one isn't) and made by an EU carrier (again, this one isn't). Thus, EU rules and compensation don't apply.

Comment: @JannaRaikhman , Which "compensation clause" exactly are you referring to?

Comment: The one that states that passengers are entitled to compensation if the flight was cancelled. 
"the Flight Operator or Organizer will pay the said Compensation to the passenger within 45 days from the date at which the passenger or the Travel Agency Service Provider, as stated in Section 15, as the case may be, has made written application to it; the Compensation will be paid in cash, by bank transfer or by check, and if the passenger has expressly agreed to such in writing -by traveler's check or by other means of payment as shall be agreed upon with him; " (Israeli Aviation Services Law)